# How to show category name in Product Page in Codigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two table in database ::: 1. tbl_category 2. tbl_product. 
Showing all category list in home page and when user clicks on signle category then it goes to product page(from tbl_product)  by category id (included category id in tbl_product)

Issue ::: I want to show the category Name and Image Here. So that user can see in which category they clicked on (from tbl_category ) ::: how can I get them ??? please help me

## Controller ::::

```
class Home extends CI_Controller{
//put your code here
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('home_model');
}
public function index(){
    $data=array();

    $data['result']=$this->home_model->selectCategory($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));

    $data['maincontent']=$this->load->view('home_message',$data,TRUE);
    $this->load->view('home', $data);
}

public function category($category_id){
    $data=array();

    $data['result']=$this->home_model->selectProductByCategoryId($category_id);

    $data['maincontent']=$this->load->view('category_detail',$data,TRUE);
    $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

## Model::::

```
class Home_Model extends CI_Model{
//put your code here


public function selectCategory($per_page, $offset)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_category');
    $this->db->order_by("category_id", "desc"); 

    $query = $this->db->get('', $per_page, $offset);
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        $data[] = $row;

    return $data;

} 

    public function selectProductByCategoryId($category_id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_product');
    $this->db->where('category_id',$category_id);
    //$this->db->order_by("product_id", "desc"); 
    $query_result=  $this->db->get();
    $result=$query_result->result();
    return $result;
}
```

## View::::

I want to show the category Name and Image Here. So that user can see in which category they clicked on ::::

```
<?php 
        foreach ($result as $values)
        {
    ?>

    <div>
        <div>
            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>product_category/product_detail/<?php echo $values->product_id ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?><?php echo $values->product_image ?>" width="90%" height="220" /></a>
        </div>

        <div>
            <b><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>product_category/product_detail/<?php echo $values->product_id ?>"><?php echo $values->product_name ?></a></b> <br>
            <b>Price: <?php echo $values->product_price ?></b> <br>
            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>product_category/product_detail/<?php echo $values->product_id ?>" class="a-btn">Order Now</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Well, you can't possibly know the name of the category the user clicked on AND show them the contents of that category at the same time, can you?

Comment: I have category id in tbl_product but how can I get category name from tbl_category with same id ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller

```
public function category($category_id){
    $data=array();

    $data['result']   = $this->home_model->selectProductByCategoryId($category_id);

    // Added this line
    $data['category'] = $this->home_model->selectCategoryByd($category_id);

    $data['maincontent'] = $this->load->view('category_detail',$data,TRUE);
    $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

Model_Home

```
public function selectCategoryById($category_id) 
{
    $result = $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('tbl_category')
        ->where('id',$category_id)
        ->get()
        ->result();

    return $result;
}
```

Then echo some of those in your view.

You are using a `Model_Home` for other models functions?
Models are for data and everything what has to do with that data. You should have a `Model_Category` with a `selectById` function and a `Model_Product` with a `selectByCategoryId` AND a `selectById` function. Models are NOT used to describe pages.

Please read about [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and [CodeIgniters implementation of it](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/mvc.html). Then refactor your code and properly use codeigniters features which, if implemented correctly, allow you to not even have to write these functions yourself! Note: I do not know CI very well, so I don't know about the specific implementations of e.g. MVC, ORM, and the like

Comment: Getting Error ::::
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM (`tbl_category`) WHERE `id` = '15'

Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\furniture\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: Change `id` to `category_id`.

Comment: in view page I have echo like this :::: <?php echo $category->category_name; ?>

Comment: If that is how you have called your name column, then yes.

Comment: changed     id to     category_id    but getting 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/category_detail.php

Line Number: 6 :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: IN line 6 I input :::<?php echo $category->category_name; ?>

Comment: Try `$category[0]->category_name;`. It is not that clean, perhaps some CI expert can tell you how to fetch a single object from a database result.

Comment: in DB in tbl_category I have the following fields :: category_id  category_name  category_description  category_image

Comment: it's working perfectly ::: <?php echo $category[0]->category_name; ?>

Comment: Thank you so much ... I have got the solution in view page call <?php echo $category[0]->category_name; ?>

Comment: No problem. Please, read the links I gave you as your current setup is not MVC, good luck ;)

Comment: Surely I will. I am new in CI. Thanks again ... Have a super day